# Grepdiff not matching beginning or end of lines properly

Tags: regex, diff, git-diff

I'm confused about some behavior in grepdiff.  I'm trying to write a script that parses over individual hunks of a diff and looks for a pattern.  In particular, I'm looking for diffs that add and remove a line with only a minor change in a numeric value, like this:

```
@@ -2160 +2160 @@
-        "posZ": 13.912,
+        "posZ": 13.911,
```

My goal is for the script to revert these changes.  To do that, I need to detect them first.  However, I can't get grepdiff to identify lines properly.

This regex does match:

```
git diff -U0 HEAD^ | grepdiff -E '^[^0-9-]*[0-9-]+.[0-9]+,' --output-matching=hunk
```

This does not:

```
git diff -U0 HEAD^ | grepdiff -E '^[^0-9-]*[0-9-]+.[0-9]+,$' --output-matching=hunk
```

Similarly, neither does this:

```
git diff -U0 HEAD^ | grepdiff -E '^\+[^0-9-]*[0-9-]+.[0-9]+,' --output-matching=hunk
```

Without matching the beginning or ending of lines properly, I don't see how I can identify these hunks.

Comment: Try `grepdiff -E '^[^0-9-]*[0-9-]+[.][0-9]+,[[:space:]]*$'`, are there carriage returns/spaces at the end of lines?

Comment: That works, thanks.  If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
grepdiff -E '^[^0-9-]*[0-9-]+[.][0-9]+,[[:space:]]*$'
```

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^0-9-]*                 any character except: '0' to '9', '-' (0
                           or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9-]+                  any character of: '0' to '9', '-' (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [.]                      any character of: '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [[:space:]]*             any character of: whitespace characters
                           (like \s) (0 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```